# Is there a way to get user input value as they enter character by character, meaning not once they hit submit

Tags: javascript

I have the following input element(note, I don't have inside `<form>` tags:

```
       <input id = 'search' type="text">
```

And a simple script:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     let query = document.getElementById("search").value;
     console.log(query)
   </script>
```

I saw on many other answers that this was how you can get a value from an input, but the only thing printed to my console is an empty string. Is there a way to get the input on each keystroke? So say that if a user types in 'apple', the following gets printed to the console:

```
 'a',
 'ap' ,
 'app',
 'appl',
 'apple'
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Check out the [`onkeypress`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp) event. Try setting up a listener on the text box.

Comment: I think it would be more practical to add a listener to the [input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event). I don't know about the keypress event but the input one captures copy and paste as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, add an event handler to the input element and listen for the [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event)-event.

> The **input** event fires when the value of an *<input>*, *<select>*, or
> *<textarea>* element has been changed.

The [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event)-event does not necessarily fire for each alteration to an element's value.

```js
function handle(event) {
  // inside this event handler, "this" is the element that it was attached to
  // and the current value of the element can be retrieved with this.value
  console.log(this.value);
}

document.getElementById("search").addEventListener("input",handle);
```

```html
<input id = 'search' type="text">
```

Comment: This gives me an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null

Comment: @FontFamily Do you mean when you run the provided code snippet or in your own code?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I figured it out - the DOM hadn't finished finalizing. I created a handler that waits until the page is loaded before loading the script.

Answer (score -1):

try with onchange attribute in input

```
   <input id = 'search' type="text" onchange="gettext()">

   <script type="text/javascript">
   function gettext()
   {
       let query = document.getElementById("search").value;
       console.log(query)
   }
   </script>
```

Comment: From [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event): The *change* event is fired for <input>, <select>, and <textarea> elements when an alteration to the element's value **is committed** by the user. Unlike the *input* event, the *change* event **is not necessarily fired for each alteration** to an element's value.